# Can I tell which users are downloading files with SMF or PHPBB forum software?

Tags: forum, phpbb

I want to create a forum where I will have attachments available for download to registered users.  I'd like to be able to see which registered users have downloaded which files.  Is there a way to do that using SMF or PHPBB?  I don't need to have 100% accuracy, as I imagine there are probably sneaky ways of masking your download, but this will be on a forum that is not really attracting people that would be using those methods-IE these are totally legit files that people will be downloading in a business setting.

PS: The files will live on my server, so I suppose it's possible to add a second layer where a user has to enter a password, but I prefer to just have the files as attachments on the forum.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Nice-two down-votes and no comments...If there is a better place to ask this question-feel free to comment on where.

Answer (score 3):

You could append the user's ID or username as a part of a query string on the download link in your forum software's templates and periodically `grep` your webserver logs for requests on the download script and store username/file correlations -or- you could modify the download script to log to a file or update a database once a file is downloaded (if you take this route, it would be advisable to store a value from the user's session variables).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a third-party downloads service such as [e-junkie](http://www.e-junkie.com/), which offers a [free downloads feature](http://www.e-junkie.com/ej/free-checkout.htm) where users get access to downloads in return for providing their email address.

If you're looking for a solution that specifically uses SMF or phpBB, it might be worth asking on the [SMF](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php) or [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/community/) community boards. In particular, I know that phpBB already features a download counter for files attached to forum posts, so a good starting point would be to ask how you might adapt the counter code to also log the forum user who downloaded the file.